# Não consigo utilizar um método de consulta quando utilizo uma classe de conexão

Tags: php, pdo

Minha classe de conexão:

```
class Connection{

    private $host="localhost";
    private $user="root";
    private $password="";
    private $dbname="test";         

    private function conectionDB(){
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname","$this->user", "$this->password");
        return $conn;           
    }

    public function Connection(){
        $this->conectionDB();           
    }
}
```

Como estou realizando a minha chamada na index.php:

```
<?php   
require_once('class/Connection.class.php');
$pdo_conn = new Connection();
$query = "select * from qualquercoisa"
$pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);

?>
```

**O erro que me apresenta:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Connection::prepare()

Answer (score 0):

Quando você utiliza `$pdo_conn = new Connection();` você apenas instância um objeto da classe Connection, você não está criando a conexão com sua base de dados.
Para obter sua conexão com a base de dados, faça:

```
<?php   
  $pdo_conn = $pdo_conn->conectionDB();
?>
```